# Does the intersection of two dense, open sets have the Baire property?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, baire-category

*Definition:* $A \subseteq X$ for a metric space $X$ has the Baire Property if for any sequence of sets {$V_{n}$} for $n \geq 1$ that are dense and open in $A$, 
$$cl(\cap V_{n}) \cap A = A $$ for all $n \geq 1$. That is, $\cap V_{n}$ is dense in $A$.

*Question:*
Now suppose $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ are two open, dense sets of metric space $X$.
Prove that $ G_{1} \cap G_{2}$ has the Baire property.

To prove this, I need to show that for any sequence, say {$V_{n}$} s.t. each $V_{n}$ is open and dense in $ G_{1} \cap G_{2}$,

$cl(\cap V_{n}) \cap (G_{1} \cap G_{2}) = (G_{1} \cap G_{2}) $

**Attempt** $V_{n}$ dense in $G_{1} \cap G_{2}$. So $cl(V_{n})\cap (G_{1} \cap G_{2}) = (G_{1} \cap G_{2}) $. Which means $(G_{1} \cap G_{2}) \subseteq cl(V_{n}) $. Thus, $cl(G_{1} \cap G_{2}) \subseteq cl(cl(V_{n})) = cl(V_{n})$.

And since $(G_{1} \cap G_{2}) \subseteq cl(G_{1} \cap G_{2})$, we have $(G_{1} \cap G_{2}) \subseteq cl(V_{n})$.

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Seeing as the intersection of two dense open sets is a dense open set, all you have to do is prove that one dense open set has the Baire property.

Comment: But I think your instructor's or your textbook's use of the term "Baire property" is pretty confusing. To me, a set has *the property of Baire* if it's the symmetric difference of an open set and a meager set.

Comment: @bof Usually topologists say "a space is Baire", or "$X$ is a Baire space", while sets with the property of Baire are called just that. In measure theory we also consider the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the closed (or compact) $G_\delta$ sets and this is called the Baire $\sigma$-algebra. Also, "the" Baire space  is a name for $\omega^\omega$ as well. Confusing, eh?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to show that if $X$ is Baire, so is any open dense subspace $O$ of $X$. This is straightforward from the definition.

Then note that a finite intersection of dense open sets is still dense and open.

Note that in your statement $X$ needs to be Baire itself, or we could trivially take $X= G_1 = G_2 = \mathbb{Q}$ in the usual topology and have a counterexample.